# Confusion on two-point correlation function in momentum space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, correlation-functions, propagator

I am trying to understand the two-point correlation function of a massless complex scalar field in momentum space. My attempt is given below:

Let $\phi$ is a  complex scalar field and $\bar{\phi}$ is its hermitian conjugate (please note that I dropped all other indices on which $\phi$ may also depend.)

\begin{equation}
S = \int~\mathrm{d}q~\bar{\phi}(q)q^{2}\phi(-q)
\end{equation}
We wish to calculate two point correlation function,

\begin{equation}
\langle \bar{\phi}(q_{1})\phi(q_{2}) \rangle = \int\mathcal{D}\phi\mathcal{D}\bar{\phi}~\bar{\phi}(q_{1})\phi(q_{2})e^{-S}
\end{equation}

Now, define the partition function as,
\begin{eqnarray}
Z[J,\bar{J}] = \frac{1}{Z[0,0]}\int\mathcal{D}\phi\mathcal{D}\bar{\phi}~e^{-\int\mathrm{d}q~\bar{\phi}(q)q^{2}\phi(-q)-\bar{J}(q)\phi(-q)-J(-q)\bar{\phi}(q)}
\end{eqnarray}

After completing square as below

\begin{eqnarray}
\texttt{A} & = & \bar{\phi}(q)q^{2}\phi(-q)-\bar{J}(q)\phi(-q)-J(-q)\bar{\phi}(q)\\
& = & \left[\phi(-q)-q^{-2}J(-q)\right]q^{2}\left[\bar{\phi}(q)-q^{-2}\bar{J}(q)\right]-J(-q)\frac{1}{q^{2}}\bar{J}(q)
\end{eqnarray}
followed by making the following substitution

\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(-q) & \rightarrow & \phi(-q)-q^{-2}J(-q) \\
\bar{\phi}(q) & \rightarrow &  \bar{\phi}(q)-q^{-2}\bar{J}(q)
\end{eqnarray}
The partition function become,

\begin{equation}
Z[J,\bar{J}] = \exp{\int\mathrm{d}q~ J(-q)\frac{1}{q^{2}}\bar{J}(q)}
\end{equation}

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\delta}{\delta J(q_{1})} Z[J,\bar{J}] & = & \int\mathrm{d}q~ \frac{1}{q^{2}}\bar{J}(q)\delta(q_{1}+q)Z[J,\bar{J}]\\
\frac{\delta^{2}}{\delta\bar{J}(q_{2})\delta J(q_{1})} Z[J,\bar{J}] & = & \int\mathrm{d}q~ \frac{1}{q^{2}}\delta(q-q_{2})\delta(q_{1}+q)Z[J,\bar{J}]\\
\frac{\delta^{2}}{\delta\bar{J}(q_{2})\delta J(q_{1})} Z[J,\bar{J}]\Biggr|_{J=\bar{J}=0} & = & \int\mathrm{d}q~ \frac{1}{q^{2}}\delta(q-q_{2})\delta(q_{1}+q) \\
\frac{\delta^{2}}{\delta\bar{J}(q_{2})\delta J(q_{1})} Z[J,\bar{J}]\Biggr|_{J=\bar{J}=0} & = &  \frac{1}{q_{1}^{2}}\delta(q_{1}+q_{2}) \\
\Rightarrow \langle \bar{\phi}(q_{1})\phi(q_{2}) \rangle & = & \frac{1}{q_{1}^{2}}\delta(q_{1}+q_{2})
\end{eqnarray}

Then,

\begin{equation}
\langle \bar{\phi}(q_{1})\phi(q_{2}) \rangle =  \frac{1}{q_{1}^{2}}\delta(q_{1}+q_{2})
\end{equation}
This is the two-point correlation function of a scalar field in momentum space.

Now, if we choose $q_{2}=-q$ and $q_{1}=q$, then

\begin{equation}
\langle \bar{\phi}(q)\phi(-q) \rangle =  \frac{1}{q^{2}}\delta(0)
\end{equation}

> **Apparently $\delta(q_{1}+q_{2})$ in the $\bar{\phi}(q_{1})\phi(q_{2})$ is imposing the momentum conservation
> at the vertex. Nevertheless, I am not sure about how to interpret the
> physical meaning of $\delta(q_{1}+q_{2})$ correctly. I hope that
> someone can interpret its true physical meaning.**

Comment: It's indicative of momentum conservation. That is its true physical meaning. Why is that bothering you?

Comment: @ Prahar, Thank you for your remark about momentum conservation. My confusion now has gone.

Comment: @felix - ok! but that was your observation anyway! I didn't really add anything. :)